# Disabling Face Overlay of Multiple Objects

Tags: modifiers, faces, retopology

I've done something silly where the faces of my retopology layer is doing a kind of "overlay" atop my sculpt.

While I see the benefit, I only want the faces of the view I'm retopologizing visible, not the back ( highlighted yellow ).

I've toggled "in front" via viewport display and checked other view displays as depicted in the image as well as settings in my modifiers.

I'm using a mix of "Retopoflow" and methods utilized by [Grant Abbitt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sE-p8PcHDo&t=453s) and [Julien Kaspar](https://studio.blender.org/training/stylized-character-workflow/).

The only fix I can think of is disabling the "in front" within "viewport display" while raising the geometry above the sculpt via shrinkwrap's "offset". But I'm wondering if there's another method that's not that?

[Here's a google drive of my current file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Oq3311r-SeWuZ44-wRG9icdqQOMbSxtV).

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I think the best you can do is enable Backface Culling under the Viewport Shading properties. That doesn't remove the geo completely but essentially sets it to look like Hidden Wire if the polygon is facing the opposite direction. I haven't been able to find a way to have it be in front and completely invisible otherwise.

Comment: Uncheck 'In Front' in viewport display?

Comment: @RobinBetts Your suggestion solved a lot of my issues! I can more easily achieve what my initial question was trying to tackle. Thanks so much!